# Subdomain with all digits seems to be messing with /etc/hosts file

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have a /etc/hosts file that has something like this line for 127.0.0.1 for hostnames I'm using for development sites:

`127.0.0.1 localhost site1.example.com site2.example.com site3.example.com`

I noticed that things broke, however, if I added in a domain with just digits to the entry:

`127.0.0.1 localhost site1.example.com site2.example.com site3.example.com 10.example.com site4.example.com`

With this line, `site4.example.com` no longer resolved to 127.0.0.1 but to the IP address for example.com. So it's as if it didn't exist in the `/etc/hosts` file. The first couple of sites still resolved to 127.0.0.1.  But **anything placed after** the `10.example.com` entry no longer resolves to 127.0.0.1. If I remove the `10.example.com` entry, it resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Anyone knows why a subdomain with all digits might mess with `/etc/hosts`?

This is on a Mac.

Comment: Hmm, looks like subdomains that begin with a number might be illegal: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt

Comment: You might be interested by this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875771/6368697 ; TL;DR  for you, since RFC1123, labels starting with a digit are completely LEGAL (otherwise `3com.com` couldn't exist, which was a problem back at the time for the well known "3Com" company)

Comment: "I noticed that things broke" How? Where? I just tried on MacOS Catalina, with `127.127.127.127 test1.example.com 1test.example.com 42.example.com test2.example.com` in my `/etc/hosts`, and  all four names are resolved fine (for example with `ping -c 1 -t 1 test1.example.com`.

Comment: Very weird. I'll post my entire /etc/hosts file when I get a chance.